# Image of Exact Sequence under surjective maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra

Let $$\dots\to A\to B\to C\to \dots$$ be an exact sequence of $R$-modules.

If $f_i$ are a family of surjective morphisms, say $f_A: A\to f(A)$, $f_B: B\to f(B)$, etc, is this enough to ensure that $$\dots\to f_A(A)\to f_B(B)\to f_C(C)\to\dots$$ is an exact sequence?

Thanks. I am aware this is related to the topic of exact functors, which I am new to.

If no, is there any simple counterexamples? Also, are there any additional conditions that we can impose to make the statement true?

Thanks.

Comment: A "surjective morphism"? From what to what?

Comment: Sorry, I mean a family of surjective morphisms, see the edit above.

Comment: No commutativity requirements for the $f_\bullet$?

Comment: You might want to look at the snake lemma.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen At the moment no commutativity requirements.

Answer (score 1):

No.

Let $R=\Bbb Z$, $A_1=A_2=\Bbb Z$ and $A_n= 0$ otherwise, $A_1\to A_2$ the identity.
Let $B_1=\Bbb Z$ and $B_n=0$ otherwise. Then we have obvious epimorphims $A_n\to B_n$, but $B_\bullet $ is not exact.